# How do I make 2 color line below the AppBar?

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I make 2 color line below the AppBar?

Like this below image showed!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it: Example Code -

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 5.0,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 5.0,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.square(1.0)),
        ),
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir @anmol-majhail.  Love you sir :) Working superBBBB!